# How do I take ownership of files from another instance of Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I have two instances of Windows 10 on two different hard drives; the newer one is a on a SSD. There are files from the previous instance of Win 10 which I would like to access (for instance, Google Drive files) but the new instance has no permission; even after I try to "take permission" of the folder, I still cannot do so.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This is because by default, windows will set the OS disks to read-write protection to prevent other OS(s) to modify them.

IN THE OLD OS: *MUST BE BOOTED FROM*

To fix this, type

DISKPART into the start menu. Then, write LIST DISK. This will give you numbers of drives. Select the hard drive number. Next, type SELECT DISK X *where x is th number*.  Now,  type ATTRIBUTES DISK CLEAR READ-ONLY. If this works, the console will state so.

Now reboot from the new drive and try again. This time yiu should have acess.